# How to change terminal in visual studio code (on linux)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to try run program.c in visual studio code on linux and this message appears:

```
Unable to start debugging. No terminal is available to launch the debugger. Please install Gnome Terminal or XTerm.
```

I'm not using xterm, only urxvt. I have already changed

```
"terminal.external.linuxExec": "urxvt",
```

in settings.json, but it is not enough.

What to do next to use urxvt instead required xterm or Gnome Terminal, please?

Comment: Try to restart the VS Code instance.